# Opening new views, does it happen in the controller?

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I am used to web MVC where this would happen each event/request:

1. Clicks link for site.com/login
2. Router would figure out where the user is going
3. Dispatcher would load up the Login controller

I am attempting MVC in Java and I have hit a little bump with the flow of things.

The user clicks a button to open a new window, the controller catches this event. We are currently in the controller so is this the place where you dispose/hide the current window and load up the new controller which will in turn display the new requested window?

It is the only place I can think of or are there better ways to accomplish this? Something does not seem right about it to me.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Are you using a framework for MVC, or just trying to understand the pattern?  In a true MVC pattern, the controller modifies the model, which updates the view, which the user sees and modifies the controller.  However, in practice, it doesn't really work like that.

Comment: I understand it and have the view observing the model layer etc but I am lost as to where you load up new controllers and views after an event like someone clicks a button and a new window is supposed to appear.

Comment: Again, highly dependent on how you are implementing "MVC".  For instance, the PureMVC framework uses an event model and Command objects to wire things together, and most of the view manipulation (showing a view, hiding a view, etc) is done in the controller, from what I remember.  Purists may argue that view-related stuff should be triggered in the View, though most implementations I have seen do this in the Controller since the Model should be rather dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Use case for login is different from regular controller. Login should be called anytime unauthenticated user tries to access secure pages. So for login controller you could pass the url of the page user tries to access, so the Login Controller could redirect to it after Login is processed.

For regular controllers, depending on what they do you could return all the model and the view for the new page in the same controller which processes the request (This is especially true for GET requests). For post you could either return the model or redirect.

Comment: That is using HTTP though and web MVC. I am doing MVC in a desktop application.

Comment: I see. But I think the logic still applies: if you need to display something, that would be one controller. If you save, the controller does the save and returns the updated data to the view. If you need to change the window on the save (or login): then you redirect to controller responsible for that window.